# Receiving character shards when at 7 stars

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

After promoting a character to 7 stars, what happens when you receive additional shards for that character?

Will they be saleable, wasted, converted to a different character, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [a new update for the app](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes/id921022358?mt=8) which features a "Shard Store" where you can trade extra shards for other character shards:

> **What's New in Version 0.3.0**
>   Get ready for the exclusive limited-time Grand Master’s Training event! It’s the only way to get the powerful Grand Master Yoda – and only until March 15th. Each difficulty Tier may be completed once, with the sought-after rewards of Grand Master Yoda Shards, Crystals, and heavy credit sums. Complete the majority of the difficulty tiers to earn enough Shards to activate Grand Master Yoda himself, and complete all difficulty Tiers to fully Promote Grand Master Yoda to Seven Star! Plus, only a full party of Jedi may challenge the Grand Master, with each difficulty tier requiring the corresponding Star Rarity of the party members. The full update also includes:
>   • The Shard Shop, where you can trade in extraneous Shards towards other characters
>   • The ability to preview a PVP opponent’s full squad in Squad Arena
>   • Gear updates – Now, individual gear indicates if equippable by characters in your squad, and Gear Found Notifications are marked as such within the reward preview window
> Plus, we’ve made some behind-the-scenes updates to help preview potential pack drops in the store, make collecting energy via daily activities easier, make battling even better, and more. Thanks, as always, for playing!

Update to this version if you'd like to trade your extra shards for something useful!

Answer (score 1):

It's worth adding that this also applies to ship shards.

You receive 15 shard shop currency for each excess character shard and 19 shard shop currency for each excess ship shard.